# Error initializing Alchemy Provider in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, ethereum

I want to init alchemy json Provider in next.js

the alchemy url with key is stored inside **env.local** like so-

**ALCHEMY_URL=https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/myAlchemyKey**

> page: /nft

```
 const alchemyUrl = process.env.ALCHEMY_URL

 console.log("** ethersAlchemyProvider **")
 const ethersAlchemyProvider =  new 
 ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(alchemyUrl)
 // console.log(ALCHEMY_URL)
 //console.log(ethersAlchemyProvider)
```

If the above is not possible in next.js, can you show me how I should init ethers provider serverSide and pass it inside the /nft page as prop, this what I tried-

```
 export async function getServerSideProps() {
  var ethers = require('ethers')

   // init alchemy provider here
  const ethersAlchemyProvider =  new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.ALCHEMY_URL)
  
   // Pass data to the page via props
   return { props: { ethersAlchemyProvider } }
 }
```

It gives me this error-

[image]

Basically I want to initialize the ethers-provider using that alchemy-key inside env.local.

am using **"next": "12.0.10"**

Answer (score 0):

I struggled on the same problem. I solved it by retrieving the values I wanted on the server side, then rendering the page with the values passed as props, see below

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers"

 export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // executed when the page myPage is requested from the client
    // everything here is executed on the server side
     const ethersAlchemyProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.ALCHEMY_URL)
     const myContract = new ethers.Contract(myContractAddresse, myContractabi, ethersAlchemyProvider)
     const tx = await myContract.myFunction()

    // we tell to the client side, to the browser to render myPage with the tx props
     return { props: { tx } }
}

export default function myPage({ myValue }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {myValue}
        </div>
    )
}
```